# JQuery Autocomplete doesnt close

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JQuery to display an autocomplete list, I have the following to close the list when clicked outside:

```
$(document).bind('click', function (event) {
        // Check if we have not clicked on the search box
        if (!($(event.target).parents().andSelf().is('#showmore'))) {           
            $(".ui-menu-item").display = 'none';
            $(".ui-menu-item").remove();            

        }
    });
```

The list closes but not completely! The following image shows a small white area beneath the text box.

[image]

The html on the page shows the following:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: block; top: 423.5625px; left: 272.875px; width: 361px;"></ul>
```

Though I have closed the autocomplete and set its display to none, its still there! PLease help me resolve this.

Comment: Could you share more code or setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: You're hiding the list items but actually you must hide the ul. Because yhe white background element is the ul which is being shown :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code,

You must hide the `ul` instead of `ui-menu-item`.

So you must have `$(".ui-menu").hide()` to hide that white background element below the search box.

In your code,

```
if (!($(event.target).parents().andSelf().is('#showmore'))) {           
     $(".ui-menu").hide();  
}
```

And also you've following snippet in your code:

```
  $(".ui-menu-item").display = 'none';
```

which should be

```
  $(".ui-menu-item").hide();
```

There is no `display` property in `jQuery` wrapped dom element.

If you want to use `display: none` then do it with

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ui-menu-item").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: There is no point in hiding it, he removes it right after that.

Comment: @blex Yes that's true. But the display property in jQuery wrapped object is wrong, that's why pointed it out. Need more code to predict the exact issue. But what i predict to be the issue is the parent element wrapping the autocomplete is being shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. I think your click outside is not working properly. And there is syntax error in the code as well.

```
$(".ui-menu-item").display = 'none'; // this should be 
$(".ui-menu-item").hide(); //instead
```

---

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("ui-menu-item"); // change ui-menu-item to your desired one

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it).